# This migration to Stack Overflow was erroneous

Tags: support, migration, on-topic, stackoverflow

The question
[Automatically add comma to end of JavaScript objects in VSCode](https://superuser.com/q/1367141/150988)
(see [Revision History here](https://superuser.com/posts/1367141/revisions))
was erroneously migrated to Stack Overflow.

This is clearly a software use question –
about using the Visual Studio Code ([VSCode](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vscode)) text editor,
and getting it to automatically insert commas after braces.

It is not on topic on Stack Overflow –
it's by no means a programming question.

Is there a way to reverse the migration?

Comment: BTW — it’s not a problem, and none of my business, really, but — are you aware that your accounts on [Super User](//superuser.com/users/119570), [Mathematics SE](//math.stackexchange.com/users/25565/user1068446), [Electrical Engineering SE](//electronics.stackexchange.com/users/7913/user1068446), [Ask Ubuntu](//askubuntu.com/users/93587/user1068446) and [Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com/users/236516/user1068446) all still have your original “user1068446” user name, while (AFAICT) all your other accounts carry your “real name”? It should be easy to fix that; maybe even all at once.

Answer (score 4):

1. I agree that too many questions
   that are posted on a site where they are on-topic
   get erroneously migrated to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com). 
   This is a bigger problem on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com),
   where some people react to anything that looks like source code
   the way people in warm climes react to a snowflake,
   but I guess it’s a problem here on Super User, too.
2. While I tentatively agree that
   [Automatically add comma to end of JavaScript objects in VSCode](https://superuser.com/q/1367141/150988)
   is on-topic at Super User,
   I believe (as a very low-involvement member)
   that it is on-topic at Stack Overflow *also:*
   [“software tools commonly used by programmers”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
   are explicitly listed as being on-topic there. 
   In any case, Stack Overflow seems to be happy to accept questions
   that belong on Super User or U & L,
   such as how to run commands from the command line,
   on the (IMHO flimsy) rationale that
   anything that could be used on the command line could be used in a script,
   and therefore it’s programming-related. 
   (Similar rationale for [Excel worksheet formula](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/worksheet-function) questions, I suppose.)
3. I am sorely tempted, even now, to vote to close
   [Automatically add comma to end of JavaScript objects in VSCode](https://superuser.com/q/1367141/150988)
   as unclear, because,

   - It’s hard to understand the premise
     for a reader who is not proficient in JavaScript.
   - Specifically, it shows examples of lines that say `{},`
     and then talks about typing `{` and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>,
     without providing context.
   - Even with the latest edit, it’s not clear what’s happening. 
     When you type `{` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, does [VSCode](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vscode)

     - Give you an error message?
     - Open two blank lines, and

       - insert `}` on the second line, and
       - insert “//Missing comma!” as a comment on the second line?

     If VSCode is inserting the `}`, and you want it to insert `},` instead,
     it would help if you would *say so,* explicitly,
     and ***show*** the desired result. 
     This is a common guideline on Super User and U & L: *show*

     - the input (your starting state),
     - what you do,
     - what happens (what you get), and
     - ***what you want to get***.

     If VSCode ***isn’t*** inserting the `}`,
     then I really don’t know what you want. 
     (I mean really. 
     I am not just being pedantic.)

Answer (score 2):

Reversing a migration isn't possible, but I think I see both sides of the issue *sigh* I'll reopen, have a word with a few people, and strongly recommend screentogif for making a [gif](https://www.screentogif.com)